# Нагрузочное тестирование приложения, что мы должны проверять?

Tags: java, многопоточность, mysql

Всем привет!

Есть простейшее консольное java-приложение, добавляет значения в базу, что-то из неё читает. И есть тестовый клиент запускающий много потоков на чтение/запись.

Если исходить из правильного понимая нагрузочного тестирования, что обычно в таких случаях надо проверять?

P.S.: понятное дело, что сами значения в базе могут быть какими угодно, поэтому не могу сообразить что тут делать. Разве что проверить отсутствие эксепшенов и наличие увеличенных данных по определенным ключам.

Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Все это зависит от требований к вашему приложению. Цель нагрузочного тестирование - это проверка того, что система удовлетворяет неким изначальным требованиям (кол-во пользователей, выполняющих доступ к системе одновременно, времена откликов и т.п.). Вы должны сами определиться с требованиями.

Навскидку можно выделить следующие метрики:

1. Время обработки запросов каждого типа. Имеет смысл брать как мимальное/максимальное время, среднее время, так и разбивку времен ответов по перцентилям (например 75%, 90%, 95%, 99%)
2. RPS (кол-во запросов в секунду). Здесь стоит найти RPS, при котором система начинает деградировать (т.е. время обработки запросов увеличивается).
3. Т.к. работа с БД сильно зависит от объема данных, то возможно имеет смысл найти такой объем данных (например кол-во записей в таблице), при котором деградирует производительность БД (а значит и вся система).
4. Отношение успешно выполненных запросов к ошибкам (ошибки обычно бывают еще и разного типа)

Дополнительно с хостов снимают метрики, связанные с объем ввода/вывода на файловой системе, загрузка CPU, использование памяти.

Но нужно четко понимать, что и зачем вы тестируете, как одна метрика влияет на другую.